# Need a php script to upload bitmapdata into a mysql table (BLOB) from Flash AS3

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3, upload

I need help in a php script. Have spent half a day searching high and low but couldnt get anything work.

Basically, i want a sample php script, that can let me call from Flash, to save a bitmap data as a record into a mysql table!

Thanks...

Comment: Flash is perfectly capable of doing a regular HTTP POST, which can be a file upload. As such, any PHP script which can accept a file upload would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Flash is concerned, you need to turn your BitmapData object into a [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html)

Look into Zend AMF or amfphp for communication with PHP, both will allow you to pass the ByteArray as a variable .
[Zend Amf](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.amf.html)
[Lee Brimelow | ZendAmf Video tutorial](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=90)

As for the PHP script, as soon as you get the ByteArray variable in PHP, it's a straightforward Mysql connection , only you need to save your data as a blob.
[Store images in Mysql tutorial](http://www.techcubetalk.com/2009/01/tutorial-on-how-to-store-images-in-mysql-blob-field/)